# Can't load executable from memory, VB.NET assembly

Tags: windows, vb.net, powershell, .net-assembly

So basically, I'm trying to load exe file into memory and run its **Main** function.

It's coded in **VB.NET** and it has a Namespace called **ConApp** and a Module called **MyModule**

So far I've tried this in powershell:

```
$path = [path to exe]
$bytes = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($path)
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($bytes)
```

And this is the output:

```
GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False  v4.0.30319
```

So I assume it's loaded here? And then when I try to call it like this:

```
[ConApp.MyModule]::Main()
```

I get this error:

```
Unable to find type [ConApp.MyModule].
At line:1 char:1
+ [ConApp.MyModule]::Main()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ConApp.MyModule:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

Any ideas on how could I achieve the execution from memory? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was actually simple, I wasn't calling the assemblyname first.

So it should've been:

```
[ConApp.ConApp.MyModule]::Main()
```

instead of:

```
[ConApp.MyModule]::Main()
```